# Find exact limit of recurrence relation $x_{n+1}=\cos(x_n)+1, x_0=1$

Tags: recursion

I did this:

```
b[x_] := Cos[b[x - 1]] + 1; b[0] = 1;
num = SequenceLimit[N[Table[b[n], {n, 1, 100}], 50]]
```

I also did the listplot which shows a convergent value. [image: the recurrence relation]
Both results suggests that SequenceLimit did the right thing.

The limit is 1.2834287895560837995226068447.

Is there a way to find the exact value of convergent recurrence relation?
Or find the limit without repeated calculation ?

Comment: Did you try with `Rsolve[]`? Although, I doubt it will succeed.

Comment: the limit is simply the solution to `x=cos[x]+1` not much you can do analytically with that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for fun but agreement with limit:

First note that the limit is the fixed point of Cos[u]+1==u:

```
$MachinePrecision -> 50
N[Nest[N[Cos[#] + 1, 50] &, 1, 10000], 50]
```

yields:

```
1.2834287417457653167971306006330447437054356272077
```

Solving the fixed point equation:

```
rt = Solve[Cos[u] + 1 == u && 0 < u < Pi, u];
N[u /. First[rt], 50]
```

yields:

```
1.2834287417457653167971306006330447437054356272077
```

Sacrificing precision but for illustration and visualization:

```
ln = NestList[{#[[2]], Cos[#[[2]]] + 1} &, {Pi/2, 1}, 100];
lines = Partition[
   Flatten[{{#1, #2}, {#2, #2}, {#2, Cos[#2] + 1}} & @@@ ln], 2];
pt = SequenceLimit[N[ln[[All, 2]], 50]];
```

Visualizing (a little slow to evaluate on my machine) then exporting as gif:

```
tab=Table[Show[Plot[{Cos[x] + 1, x}, {x, 0, Pi}], 
  Graphics[{Line[lines[[1 ;; j]]], {Red, Point[{pt, pt}]}}], 
  ImageSize -> 500], {j, 1, 303}];
```

[image]